# I have a component which loads embedded YouTube video as below

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

```
const videoSrc =  `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${video.id.Id}`;
<iframe src = {videoSrc}/>
```

but it keeps on showing the error that
`An error occurred. Try again later` or
`TroubleShoot it.`

Comment: Do you need quotes around `src=`? `src="{videoSrc}" />`

Comment: It should work, check - `video.id.Id`

Comment: @HanletEscaño : It should work without quotes

Comment: @swapnesh true.

Comment: Are you sure that the video id is correct?

Comment: Thanks all i resolved the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happened because your video embedded id is wrong so Get the right video id from youtube( `embedId` inside code) Refer Link:https://help.tcgplayer.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008106868-Finding-Your-YouTube-Video-ID

```
const videoSrc =  `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`;
<iframe src = {videoSrc}/>
```